# Trying to Display the File name within a ComboBox.Items.AddRange()

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to make it so that I only have to use one line of code in my .NET application. Here's what I have:

```
string[] files = Directory.getfiles(@"C:\");
foreach(String file in files){
    ComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Thoughts?
I want it to be like this:

```
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to put it in one line...

```
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\").Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray());
```